need big query logic for below scenario
Below is my table,
timestamp           status      name   description  
2024-06-20 11:00    SUCCESS     S1     200
2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S1     500
2024-06-20 11:02    ERROR       S1     500
2024-06-20 11:03    ERROR       S1     502
2024-06-20 11:00    ERROR       S2     500  
2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S2     505 
2024-06-20 11:02    SUCCESS     S2     200
2024-06-20 11:03    ERROR       S2     506
2024-06-20 11:04    ERROR       S2     507
2024-06-20 11:00    ERROR       S3     500  
2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S3     505 
2024-06-20 11:02    SUCCESS     S3     200
2024-06-20 11:00    SUCCESS     S4     200
2024-06-20 11:00    ERROR       S5     400
2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S5     400 
2024-06-20 11:02    ERROR       S5     400 
2024-06-20 11:03    ERROR       S5     400 
2024-06-20 11:04    ERROR       S5     400
2024-06-20 11:05    ERROR       S5     400  
2024-06-20 11:00    ERROR       S6     400 
2024-06-20 11:01    ERROR       S6     400

Case 1:
If status is ERROR and description between 500 to 509, have to consider "High" AlertType and isActive is true.
if the last status is SUCCESS and description is 200, isActive should be False alerttype is "unknown".
Case 2:
If status is "ERROR" and description as 400 and occurred more than 5 times continuously, have to consider "High" alerttype and isActive is True.
and if "ERROR" cout <=5 times isactive should be false. also the last status is SUCCESS and description is 200, isActive should be False alerttype is "unknown".
Expected Result:
name    AlertType   FirstFailedTimestamp    LastFailedTimestamp   IsActive
S1      High         2024-06-20 11:01       2024-06-20 11:03      True
S2      High         2024-06-20 11:03       2024-06-20 11:04      True
S3      High         2024-06-20 11:00       2024-06-20 11:01      False
S5      High         2024-06-20 11:00       2024-06-20 11:05      True
S6      Unknown      2024-06-20 11:00       2024-06-20 11:01      False


You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

I'd also suggest adding a pseudo code description of the algorithm in addition to the English description.  I read the cases a couple of times and still found myself struggling to understand the specification of what you want.  What is "cout" is that a typo for "count"?  Maybe consider adding a SQL statement that generates your sample data so that if a reader wanted to test, you would have provided them a table of data with which to test.

Can you double check your expected result is consistent with what you've described? "if the last status is SUCCESS and description is 200, isActive should be False alerttype is unknown" Why isn't s3 alertType 'unknown' then? It's last status is success with a 200 description.

The results you described are not very consistent but here is a sample that gives a similar output with the following assumption:
Alerttype and IsActive for each name is based on the last run i.e. MAX(timestamp).
We will need to create 2 temporary tables
1.) ErrTable that gets the last timestamp for each name and joins with the original table to select status and descriptions at last timestamp
2.) Runstable that simply holds the First and the last timestamp that the status was "ERROR" for each name.
WITH 

ErrTable as (SELECT M.T_name,M.MaxTS,T.status, T.description FROM (SELECT MAX(A_timestamp) AS MaxTS, T_name
FROM `OriginalTABLE`   GROUP BY T_name) M LEFT JOIN `OriginalTABLE`  T 
ON M.T_name = T.T_name WHERE M.MaxTS = T.A_timestamp),

Runstable as (SELECT T_name,MAX(A_timestamp) AS LastTS, MIN(A_timestamp) AS FirstTS
FROM `OriginalTABLE` WHERE status = "ERROR"  GROUP BY T_name)

SELECT E.T_name,
CASE
WHEN E.status = "ERROR" AND E.description BETWEEN 500 AND 509 THEN "High"
WHEN E.status = "SUCCESS" AND E.description = 200 THEN "Unknown"
WHEN E.status = "ERROR" AND (SELECT COUNT(description) FROM `OriginalTABLE` O WHERE O.T_name = E.T_name and O.description = 400) > 5 THEN "High"
WHEN E.status = "ERROR" AND (SELECT COUNT(description) FROM `OriginalTABLE` O WHERE O.T_name = E.T_name and O.description = 400) <= 5 THEN "Unknown"
END 
AS AlterType,

R.FirstTS AS FirstFailedTimestamp,

R.LastTS AS LastFailedTimestamp,

CASE
WHEN E.status = "ERROR" AND E.description BETWEEN 500 AND 509 THEN "True"
WHEN E.status = "SUCCESS" AND E.description = 200 THEN "False"
WHEN E.status = "ERROR" AND (SELECT COUNT(description) FROM `OriginalTABLE` O WHERE O.T_name = E.T_name and O.description = 400) > 5 THEN "True"
WHEN E.status = "ERROR" AND (SELECT COUNT(description) FROM `OriginalTABLE` O WHERE O.T_name = E.T_name and O.description = 400) <= 5 THEN "False"
END 
AS IsActive,

FROM
ErrTable E,Runstable R, `OriginalTABLE` O WHERE E.T_name = R.T_name AND E.T_name = O.T_name 

GROUP BY E.T_name,FirstFailedTimestamp,LastFailedTimestamp,AlterType,IsActive;

OUTPUT
Query OUTPUT
I am relatively new to SQL so you can explore further optimizations to make the Query faster.
Good luck.
